# Percentage summary in a dataframe

Tags: r, summary

I have a sample dataset like the following:

```
a <- structure(list(Occ = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 8, 5), 
Type = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "B"), 
          Alc = c("A", "B", "N", "A", "N", "N", "N", "A", "B", "B")), 
          .Names = c("Occ", "Type", "Alc"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
a
   Occ Type Alc
1    1    A   A
2    2    B   B
3    3    C   N
4    4    A   A
5    4    A   N
6    5    A   N
7    6    B   N
8    4    C   A
9    8    C   B
10   5    B   B
```

I use `lapply` to find the category count in each variable.

```
lapply(a, table)
$Occ

1 2 3 4 5 6 8 
1 1 1 3 2 1 1 

$Type

A B C 
4 3 3 

$Alc

A B N 
3 3 4
```

I like to get the percentage in a `dataframe` format like the following:

```
Occ    
1: 10%   
2: 10%       
3: 10%     
4: 30% 
5: 20% 
6: 10% 
8: 10% 
Type    
A: 40%     
B: 30%      
C: 30%     
Alc    
A: 30%   
B: 30%        
C: 40%
```

Comment: Are you sure you want one column as output?

Comment: Using multiple columns would not be an issue, I guess.

Comment: Use `lapply(a, function(x) paste0(round(prop.table(table(x))*100,2), "%"))`. Everything is formatted. You can either keep it as a list or turn it into something else.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a data frame to keep the output is problematic in a few ways. As one column, the headings create a confusing variable with headers and disorganized information with possible repeated row names. Secondly the row names will not make sense since they will depend on the unique values of each column. And thirdly, as a data frame with multiple columns, NA's will be created and the row names will still not match.

A list makes the most sense:

```
lst <- lapply(a, function(x) {
  tbl <- prop.table(table(x))
  res <- paste0(round(tbl*100,2), "%")
  names(res) <- names(tbl)
  res
}
)
lst
# $Occ
#     1     2     3     4     5     6     8 
# "10%" "10%" "10%" "30%" "20%" "10%" "10%" 
# 
# $Type
#     A     B     C 
# "40%" "30%" "30%" 
# 
# $Alc
#     A     B     N 
# "30%" "30%" "40%"
```